# How to get artifact from another build

Tags: teamcity

Assume there are two Builds A and B.
Build A will build source to artifact,
Build B will test the artifact generated by Build A.

How can I transfer artifact from Build A to Build B.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Build A settings:
You should set inside the `General` tab the files you want to export as an artifact at the end of the build.

**EDIT**
Artifact paths should be like:

```
out/bin/release/*.dll
out/bin/release => ./NewOut
out/bin/release/*.* => BuildA.zip
*.nupkg
```

Build B settings:
Inside the `Dependencies` tab, you can add a new Artifact dependency, specifying the build, and the path of the artifacts to get.

**EDIT** Artifact dependency path should be like:

```
out/bin/release/*.dll => ./LocalFolder
./NewOut => ./LocalFolder
*.nupkg  => ./LocalFolder
```

There is an helper on the right of the "Edit Artifact Dependency" popup, where you can select artifacts from the specified build, according to previous run of this build.

Comment: Thanks Aupest. It makes sense. For the dependency settings, could you please give me an example of how to write "Artifacts rules". I'm a little confused about it.

Comment: An exemple might be: `out/bin/release/*.dll`
If you want to do some redirections, from a specific folder to another `out/bin/release/ => ./NewOut` And, to send the result to a zip, you can set `out/bin/release/*.* => BuildA.zip`